# Reading network computer names using mfc in windows 10

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-10-desktop

I tried to read network computer names using WNetOpenEnum. I am getting only 'Microsoft Terminal Services', 'Microsoft Windows Network' and 'Web Client Network'. Not getting the other machine connected in network.
Is there any way to read the names/IP of computers connected to network?.

```
if(NO_ERROR == WNetOpenEnum(RESOURCE_GLOBALNET, RESOURCETYPE_ANY, 0, pnetrParent, &hEnum))
{
    DWORD dwCount = 1;
    char szBuffer[512];
    char* psz = szBuffer;
    DWORD dwBufferSize = sizeof(szBuffer);
    while (NO_ERROR == WNetEnumResource(hEnum, &dwCount, &szBuffer, &dwBufferSize))
    {
        NETRESOURCE* pnetResource = (NETRESOURCE*)psz;
        if (NULL != pnetResource->lpRemoteName && *pnetResource->lpRemoteName)
        {
            m_lstIPAddress.AddString(pnetResource->lpRemoteName);               
        }
        dwBufferSize = sizeof(szBuffer);
    }
    DWORD retValue = WNetCloseEnum(hEnum);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it recursively. `Microsoft Windows Network` has computers listed. So next call to `WNetOpenEnum` will have handle to `Microsoft Windows Network` you received as first parameter and so on.

I believe this would give you answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/enumerating-network-resources

Comment: Thank you. i tried the same but i am getting only one machine "tsclient". When i use windows File Explorer i am able see more machines under Network.

Comment: still i am getting tsclient only